# Random Graph Generator Java Code Bug

Tags: java, algorithm, random, graph, hashmap

This is my code to generate a random graph where each vertex connects to 6 other vertexes. The problem is when I run it for a couple of times, (or sometimes the first run) it stucks, it seems that the Random object's function is not able to find a random number which enforce the restrictions I put. For some Vertex number it works for some not... I have no idea what is going on... There might be something wrong with the way that I use the HashMap as well. Any idea what is going wrong?

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Graph_Generator {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i=0;i<3; i++){
    System.out.println("Enter the number of vertex: ");


    int number_vertex = sc.nextInt();
    GenerateG1(number_vertex);


    }
    sc.close();
}

public static void GenerateG1(int num_vertex){

    try {

        Random random = new Random();
        Random_Graph g6 = new Random_Graph(num_vertex);
        int num_edges = 6, to, from;

        for (int v = 0; v < num_vertex; v++) {
            from = v;
            System.out.println("v is : "+ v);
            while (g6.getEdge(from).size() < num_edges) {
                to = Math.abs(random.nextInt(num_vertex));

                while (to == from || (g6.isEdge(from, to)) || (g6.isEdge(to, from)) || (g6.getEdge(to).size() > (num_edges-1))) {
                    to = Math.abs(random.nextInt(num_vertex));

                }

                g6.setEdge(to, from);

            }
        }

        System.out
                .println("THe Adjacency List Representation of the random graph is: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < num_vertex; i++) {
            System.out.print(i + " -> ");
            List<Integer> edgeList = g6.getEdge(i);
            if (edgeList.size() == 0)
                System.out.print("null");
            else {
                for (int j = 0;; j++) {
                    if (j != edgeList.size() - 1)
                        System.out.print(edgeList.get(j) + " -> ");
                    else {
                        System.out.print(edgeList.get(j));
                        break;
                    }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        } catch (Exception E) {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong");
        }
    }

}




      public class Random_Graph 
      {
    private Map<Integer, List<Integer>> adjacencyList;

    public Random_Graph(int v) 
    {
        adjacencyList = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < v; i++)
            adjacencyList.put(i, new LinkedList<Integer>());
    }

    public void setEdge(int to, int from) 
    {
        if (to >= adjacencyList.size() || from >= adjacencyList.size())
            System.out.println("The vertices does not exists");

        adjacencyList.get(to).add(from);
        adjacencyList.get(from).add(to);
    }

    public List<Integer> getEdge(int to) 
    {
        if (to > adjacencyList.size()) 
        {
            System.out.println("The vertices does not exists");
            return null;
        }
        return adjacencyList.get(to);
    }

    public boolean isEdge( int from , int to)
    {
    return (adjacencyList.get(from).contains(to) || adjacencyList.get(to).contains(from));  

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your generation algorithm's logic. Consider next situation: `num_vertex = 8`, and during generation your algorithm joined 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 into the full graph (each vertex has an edge to each other), then it proceeds to the last vertex 7, but it can't connect it with any other vertex (because each one of them already has 6 connections), so it hangs.

Comment: I just understood that what kind of problem I am facing... how I can guarantee that ?

Comment: There is a solution on my mind, I can describe it if you still need it, however it may be a bit complicated, .

Answer (score 0):

Your method does not always find a solution. One way to generate these graphs randomly:

1. Construct an initial graph. A simple way is to connect vertex `n` with vertices `(n-3, n-2, n-1, n+1, n+2, n+3)`.
2. Randomly select any two disconnected edges and swap the pairing - if the edges are `(v1, v2), (v3, v4)` then the result can be either `(v1, v3), (v2, v4)` or `(v1, v4), (v2, v3)`. Repeat this as many times as you like.